# How do I get Azure pipelines to build a solution that contains both regular .NET 8.0 class projects *and* .NET MAUI class projects?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, maui, .net-8.0

I have a MAUI app that is targeting `net8.0` and `net8.0-android`. The Visual Studio solution contains a mix of different projects. Some of the projects are just plain .NET 8 class libraries (so that they may be consumed in any .NET app). A few other projects in the solution are MAUI class libraries, because they have functionality that is specific to MAUI, such as views and viewmodels that will be shared across several different apps.

When I build the solution in Visual Studio targeting `net8.0-android`, the entire solution and all of its projects build successfully.

However, in Azure Pipelines, the command for building the solution fails because it apparently wants the regular .NET 8 class projects to additionally contain the `net8.0-android` target framework. That should not be necessary because .NET 8 class libraries can be consumed in a MAUI application.

What is different about the build command in Azure Pipelines that it is requiring I specify the additional `net8.0-android` target framework in my non-MAUI projects?

```
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\Omitted\Tests\Omitted.Api.Client.Tests.Unit\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-android'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net8.0-android' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [D:\a\1\s\Omitted\Tests\Omitted.Api.Client.Tests.Unit\Omitted.Api.Client.Tests.Unit.csproj]
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\Omitted\Omitted.Api.Client\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-android'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net8.0-android' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [D:\a\1\s\Omitted\Omitted.Api.Client\Omitted.Api.Client.csproj]
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\Omitted\Tests\Omitted.api.Client.Tests.Integration\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-android'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net8.0-android' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [D:\a\1\s\Omitted\Tests\Omitted.api.Client.Tests.Integration\Omitted.Api.Client.Tests.Integration.csproj]
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\Common\UserFriendly\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-android'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net8.0-android' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [D:\a\1\s\Common\UserFriendly\UserFriendly.csproj]
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\Platform\Omitted.Platform.Mobile.Authentication.Interfaces\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-android'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net8.0-android' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [D:\a\1\s\Platform\Omitted.Platform.Mobile.Authentication.Interfaces\Omitted.Platform.Mobile.Authentication.Interfaces.csproj]
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\Platform\Omitted.Platform.Mobile.Authentication.Models\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-android'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net8.0-android' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [D:\a\1\s\Platform\Omitted.Platform.Mobile.Authentication.Models\Omitted.Platform.Mobile.Authentication.Models.csproj]
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\Platform\Omitted.Platform.Mobile.Common.Interfaces\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-android'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net8.0-android' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [D:\a\1\s\Platform\Omitted.Platform.Mobile.Common.Interfaces\Omitted.Platform.Mobile.Common.Interfaces.csproj]
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\Platform\Omitted.Platform.Mobile.Core\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-android'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net8.0-android' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [D:\a\1\s\Platform\Omitted.Platform.Mobile.Core\Omitted.Platform.Mobile.Core.csproj]
```

The build command in Azure pipelines:

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Build App
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dotnet publish -f net8.0-android -c Release
```

I don't want my non-MAUI projects to have the `net8.0-android` target framework, nor should I need to. What am I doing wrong in my pipeline that is preventing my non-MAUI projects from building?

Comment: Is it mandatory to have both projects in the same source code repository?

Comment: @JRichardsz, yes. The solution file should be able to contain both project types, and be built with a single command. And yes, it should be able to be contained in a single repo. In the past, I used to build very complex Xamarin projects in Pipelines that contained both Xamarin libraries and plain old .NET Standard library projects. The issue has something to do with the build command in Pipelines, and how it's not honoring the `net8.0` target framework designation in the plain old .NET 8.0 class projects.

Comment: I don't understand this in net source code strategies. Why a mobile/frontend source code should be in the same git repository of the backend source code? Maybe if the frontend and backend are using c# (similar with nodejs modern monoliths) is understandable but old because angular/vue/react is for frontend and c# for backend.  I know this is a NetFramework/TFC inheritance but with netcore and nuget, net developers could use one source code repository by application type (frontend, api/microservice, monolith, mobile, daemon, cli, desktop, etc) like other languages do.

Comment: @JRichardsz There is no backend code in this repository. It's all front-end code. Both types of .NET libraries I've mentioned (.NET class library and .NET MAUI library) are consumable in a front-end MAUI application. The difference is that the MAUI library has all kinds of x-plat UI classes in it that cannot be consumed in any other kind of application, whereas the .NET class lib projects *can*, such as the HTTP API client project in my solution. However, in other projects, I certainly put my back-end API code in the same solution as front-end code. It works well. Tons of code sharing.

Comment: @JRichardsz In other words, I hear your point about separate repos for front-end vs back-end, but that's not the issue here. This is all front-end (mobile) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Just needed to use `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task instead of the `Bash@3` task. The bash `dotnet publish -f net8.0-android -c Release` command was trying to build the entire solution, because that's what I pointed it at by default. Now, with the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task, I'm pointing it at the MAUI project folder specifically, and telling it to build whatever csproj it finds there, by using the `*.csproj` designation. And by virtue of project references, all the projects that my MAUI app depends on get built as well, including the .NET 8 class library projects.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build App
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: 'path/to/MAUI-project-folder/*.csproj'
    arguments: '-f net8.0-android -c Release'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

# - task: Bash@3
#  displayName: Build App
#  inputs:
#    targetType: 'inline'
#    script: |
#      dotnet publish -f net8.0-android -c Release
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the **/Mobile.csproj pattern is a wildcard-based expression that instructs the tool or configuration system to exclusively consider the project file named Mobile.csproj wherever it exists within the project's directory structure.
Try the following yaml file:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2022'

variables:
  NetworkConfigFileDev: network_security_config_dev
  SourceDirectory: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
  Configuration: Release-Test
  DotNetVersion: 8.x
  AndroidVersion: net8.0-android
    
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: Download KeyStore File
  name: keystore
  inputs:
    secureFile: '$(KeyStore_FileName)'

- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use Java 17'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 17
    jdkArchitectureOption: x64
    jdkSourceOption: PreInstalled
    
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: Install .NET SDK
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '$(DotNetVersion)'
    includePreviewVersions: false

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Install Maui Workload'
  inputs:
    script: 'dotnet workload install maui'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build the Android Binaries $(Configuration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/Mobile.csproj'
    arguments: '-c:$(Configuration) -f:$(AndroidVersion) -p:AndroidKeyStore=true -p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=$(keystore.secureFilePath) -p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=$(Keystore_Alias) -p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=$(Keystore_Password) -p:AndroidSigningStorePass=$(Keystore_Password)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy file from Build to Staging'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
    Contents: '**/*-Signed.apk'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    flattenFolders: true
    
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish the Staging Files.'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop_maui_android'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```